# How to import all files from a folder to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, csv, windows-10

I have a folder containing `CSV`files. I want to upload the data of all the CSVs to MongoDB. I have tried the following command:

```
for i in *.csv; do mongoimport -d mydatabase -c ${i%.*} --type csv --file $i --headerline ; done
```

I have modified it to suit my scenario. The modified command is as follows:

```
for i in "C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\Testing sample csv\*.csv"; do mongoimport -d Better -c TESTCSV --type csv --file $i --headerline ; done
```

But It is giving `error: i was unexpected at this time.`
I would like to know how I can upload all the CSVs from a folder at once. I do not want to upload them one by one. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for %i in (*.csv) do mongoimport -d Better -c TESTCSV --type csv --file "%i" --headerline
```

Make sure you run this from the directory in which the `*.csv` files are present.

Comment: yes it worked.... only double quotes were required that I have added. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've made this script for Windows that imports all CSVs in the same folder and names each collection with the name of the respective CSV.

You need to copy these lines in a .bat file, then edit the variables MONGO_HOME and db as you need:

```
TITLE MongoDB CSV Importer
SET "MONGO_HOME=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6"
SET db=datasets

for %%v in (*.csv) do "%MONGO_HOME%\bin\mongoimport.exe" -d %db% -c %%~nv --type CSV --file %%v --headerline
TITLE "Import completed!"
PAUSE
```

and this works the same for Linux shell scripts (.sh):

```
db="datasets"

for entry in *".csv"
do
  coll=$(echo "$entry" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
  echo $name
  mongoimport -d $db -c $coll --type CSV --file $coll".csv" --headerline
done
echo "end of import."
```

Hope this helps